# How can I get .htaccess to be seen when I make my site live

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file which (among other things) creates pretty urls. Here's a sample of part of the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
...
# Pretty urls
RewriteRule ^home(\d+)*$ ./index.html
RewriteRule ^contact(\d+)*$ ./contact.html
RewriteRule ^enquire(\d+)*$ ./enquire.html
RewriteRule ^terms(\d+)*$ ./terms.html
RewriteRule ^about(\d+)*$ ./about.html
RewriteRule ^owners(\d+)*$ ./owners.html
```

I am currently moving the site to new hosting on digitalocean. When I test the site out by browsing the IP e.g.

```
111.222.333.444/html_docs/contact
```

the .htaccess file is working perfectly. Rewrite rules are on and the site properly rewrites the url and serves (in this case, **contact.html**) to the browser.

When I change the nameservers and browse the site by domain after propogation e.g.

```
mydomain.com/contact
```

the .htacces file fails to do the redirect, at least, it seems like it's not being seen at all. This is weird to me since it works when I'm browsing by ip. I purposely put some rubbish into the .htaccess to test if it was being picked up. Again, if I browse via the ip I get a 500 which I would expect, but when browsing by domain name I do not get an error but the rewrites don't work.

I'm banging my head at this stage and can't figure it out. Any help appreciated,

many thanks,

Wittner

Comment: Are you sure your domain is resolving to the correct IP after change? Set you TTL low to like 5 minutes in DNS for testing to make sure it's doing it quickly. You can check propagation here https://www.whatsmydns.net/. After that verify your domain name is listed correctly in your virtual host config file in apache in the `SERVER_NAME` directive.

Comment: Thanks Panama Jack. I have put a little html in the index page of the site of the new server so that I can check I'm browsing on the right IP and that side of things is fine. So a standard call to an HTML page works fine, it's just the .htaccess is not being picked up. Good point on the TTL though anyway, I'll use that thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was less of a lack of knowledge about how .htaccess works and more to do with not configuring my vhosts settings properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com/html_docs/"

    <Directory "/var/www/mydomain.com/html_docs/"> <-- Problem was here
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Turns out that in the  tag I had left out the path to my domain root. So when I directly browsed the site via the IP the system was able to figure it out, but no while browsing. All my .htaccess stuff is now working. Thanks to all who looked and anyone who replied. Live and learn I guess :-)

cheers,

Wittner